# mouse pressed->drag->released. in java

Tags: java, swing, mouse, mouseevent, drag-and-drop

Excuse me:

I just can't know how to link these successive operation?

Mouse pressed and then drag then release. If an user doesn't do this operation some action won't happen...

Should I add code as the is already pressed to distinguish that?

The constant MOUSE_MOVED doesn't work since Eclipse told me it doesn't know it although I find the parameter in [mouse event api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_MOVED)

I don't know what's going on... Please help!

Answer (score 6):

Implement a [MouseInputListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MouseInputListener.html) using a [MouseInputAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MouseInputAdapter.html) subclass and handle the mousePressed, mouseDragged, and the mouseReleased events.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class that encapsulates the drag detection:

```
public abstract static class MouseDragListener {
    java.awt.Component component;
    MouseEvent dragStart;

    public MouseDragListener(java.awt.Component component) {
        super();
        this.component = component;
        component.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                dragStart = null;
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (dragStart == null)
                    dragStart = e;
            }
        });
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (dragStart != null) {
                    dragReleased(dragStart, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

then to use:

```
new MouseDragListener(center){
    void dragReleased(MouseEvent start,MouseEvent end){
           //  do something ...
    }
}
```